# Changing woocommerce breadcrumb span to h1

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, themes, hook-woocommerce

I would like to change woocommerce breadcrumb from **span** to **h1** .nasa-first-breadcrumb.

Would really appreciate the help. I have 0 knowledge of programming. :(

```
<nav class="breadcrumb-row text-center" style="height:130px;">

<span class="nasa-first-breadcrumb"> text example</span>

<span class="breadcrumb"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></span>                   

 </nav>
```

Comment: No help, but I am trying... JSfiddle working, but if put this in function.php I get : syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'                                                                                                 $('.nasa-first-breadcrumb').each(function() {
    
  $(this).replaceWith($('<h1 class="nasa-first-breadcrumb">' + this.innerHTML + '</h1>'));
 
});

Comment: Welcome at SO. But its not the best idea asking programming questions if you have no knowledge about it...